# Deleting first five lines of a text file

Tags: java, arrays, loops, text

I'm trying to delete the first 5 lines of a text file that match five values stored in an array.  Here's what I have so far...

```
void write(String[] activecode) throws IOException
{

    File productcodes = new File("productcodes.txt");

    String charset = "UTF-8";

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(productcodes), charset));
    File temp = File.createTempFile("productcodes", ".txt", productcodes.getParentFile());

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(temp), charset));

    int counter = 0;

    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null && counter != activecode.length;) 
    {
        line = line.replace(activecode[counter], "");
        writer.println(line);
        counter++;
    }

    reader.close();
    writer.close();


    productcodes.delete();
    temp.renameTo(productcodes);   

}
```

Also for reference, here is what the text file looks like...

```
BH390311ED6911-D8P8-BG7X
BH390311ED6912-GXKQ-BQ9V
BH390311ED6913-B6JF-55YG
BH390311ED6914-7B56-W37Y
BH390311ED6915-HPDW-V949
BH390311ED6916-3XX4-NDSN
BH390311ED6917-JH4M-PK6B
BH390311ED6918-WQKJ-5TKG
BH390311ED6919-TKS3-WHG3
BH390311ED6920-QTJV-9F43
BH390311ED6921-D45V-GHNG
BH390311ED6922-JH5F-4KXM
BH390311ED6923-6NQM-WSWF
BH390311ED6924-DMFD-BTN6
BH390311ED6925-7883-JG67
BH390311ED6926-3GRN-W7YT
BH390311ED6927-CBKB-47RW
```

The array is already saved as the first five values of the text file.

Any got any ideas on why the output is the text file with only the first three values remaining?  I'm very new to Java (as you can probably tell :D)

EDIT:
The contents of the array activecode[] is:

```
BH390311ED6911-D8P8-BG7X
BH390311ED6912-GXKQ-BQ9V
BH390311ED6913-B6JF-55YG
BH390311ED6914-7B56-W37Y
BH390311ED6915-HPDW-V949
```

My desired output would be:

```
BH390311ED6916-3XX4-NDSN
BH390311ED6917-JH4M-PK6B
BH390311ED6918-WQKJ-5TKG
BH390311ED6919-TKS3-WHG3
BH390311ED6920-QTJV-9F43
BH390311ED6921-D45V-GHNG
BH390311ED6922-JH5F-4KXM
BH390311ED6923-6NQM-WSWF
BH390311ED6924-DMFD-BTN6
BH390311ED6925-7883-JG67
BH390311ED6926-3GRN-W7YT
BH390311ED6927-CBKB-47RW
```

Which is the original file minus the contents of the array.

Comment: Your for loop counter should really be in the parenthesis. e.g.: for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null && counter != activecode.length; counter++) { ... }

Comment: If you're trying to copy the rest of the input file to the output, after the first five lines, there's no code in your program that does that.  I'm not clear on what you're trying to do, though.  I think telling us exactly what the contents of `activecode[]` is, and what you expect the output file to look like, would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the loop in your code:

```
for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null && counter != activecode.length;) 
{
    line = line.replace(activecode[counter], "");
    writer.println(line);
    counter++;
}
```

Here's what it does: For `counter` = 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4, it reads a line from the input file.  `line.replace(activecode[counter],"")` will look for the code from `activecode` in the input line.  If it finds it, it removes it from the line.  If the entire `line` equals the entire `activecode[counter]` element, then the line is replaced by an empty string `""`.

But then you write the line to the file.  If your intent was to delete the lines from the file, this doesn't do that.  `line` is now (probably) an empty string, and `writer.println(line)` will write an empty string to the output file.  I'm not entirely sure what your needs are; it may be something like

```
if (!line.equals(activecode[counter]))
    writer.println(line);
```

which will write out the line unless it equals `activecode[counter]`, and if they're equal, it will skip the line and not write anything out.  However, I'm not clear on what the exact requirements are--for instance, if the *third* line in the file equals `activecode[0]`, what's supposed to happen?  So I don't know whether the above is the correct solution.  I think you'll need to define (at least for yourself) exactly what the program is supposed to do.

Finally, after this loop is done, your program doesn't read any more of the input.  That is, it only reads the first five lines.  Then it closes the input and output files.  If you need to read the rest of the input file and copy it to the output file, you'll need to write another loop to do that.